# How to adjust population weights block wise along with adjusting the religion weights?

Tags: statistics, spss, methodology

For example, in a particular block with actual population of 100 000 and with religion ratio as 60-20-20 as Hindu, Muslims, other respectively. and the sample we have collected is 1000 and religion ratio as 30-60-10.

How to add weights such that the sample base will be equal to actual population as well as adjusting the religion ratio?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below for SPSS. First we calculate the ratios between population and sample that we'd like to apply, then apply conditionally (by sample block).  Lastly, turn on the sample weights.

```
* compute ratios .
COMPUTE pop_sample_ratio = 100000 / 1000 .
COMPUTE hindu_ratio = 60 / 30 .
COMPUTE muslim_ratio = 20 / 60 .
COMPUTE other_ratio = 20 / 10 .

* calculate sample weights .
IF (religion = 'hindu') wgt = pop_sample_ratio * hindu_ratio .
IF (religion = 'muslim') wgt = pop_sample_ratio * muslim_ratio .
IF (religion = 'other') wgt = pop_sample_ratio * other_ratio .
EXE .

* apply weights .
WEIGHT BY wgt .
```

To turn off sample weights:

```
WEIGHT OFF .
```